# stripeのpaymentIntent.statusに上手く型が当てられない。

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

stripeの公式サンプルコードに型を当てているのですが、エラーが出力される。
型注釈は使用しているのですが、こちらはどのように型を当てたら良いのでしょうか？

エラー内容

```
(parameter) paymentIntent: any
Argument of type '({ paymentIntent }: PaymentIntent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: PaymentIntentResult) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'PaymentIntentResult' is not assignable to type 'PaymentIntent'.
      Type '{ paymentIntent: PaymentIntent; error?: undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 'PaymentIntent': id, object, amount, canceled_at, and 16 more.ts(2345)
Property 'paymentIntent' does not exist on type 'PaymentIntent'.ts(2339)
```

コード

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// stripeのコンポーネントを読み込んでる
import {
  PaymentElement,
  useStripe,
  useElements
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

import { PaymentIntent } from "@stripe/stripe-js";


// import { CardElementType } from './types/stripe'

export default function CheckoutForm() {
  // 第一配列がデフォルトの値, 第二配列がそれを変更する関数が入る

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  type = Payme

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!stripe) {
      return;
    }

    //URLのクエリから値を取得する
    const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
      "payment_intent_client_secret"
    );

    // リダイレクト時にここに値が入る
    if (!clientSecret) {
      return;
    }

    stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret).then(({ paymentIntent }: PaymentIntent) => {
      switch (paymentIntent.status) {
        case "succeeded":
          setMessage("Payment succeeded!");
          break;
        case "processing":
          setMessage("Your payment is processing.");
          break;
        case "requires_payment_method":
          setMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
          break;
        default:
          setMessage("Something went wrong.");
          break;
      }
    });
  }, [stripe]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
      // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);

    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
        return_url: "http://localhost:3000",
      },
    });

    // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
    // confirming the payment. Otherwise, your customer will be redirected to
    // your `return_url`. For some payment methods like iDEAL, your customer will
    // be redirected to an intermediate site first to authorize the payment, then
    // redirected to the `return_url`.
    if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
      setMessage(error.message);
    } else {
      setMessage("An unexpected error occured.");
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement id="payment-element" />
      <button disabled={isLoading || !stripe || !elements} id="submit">
        <span id="button-text">
          {isLoading ? <div className="spinner" id="spinner"></div> : "Pay now"}
        </span>
      </button>
      {/* Show any error or success messages */}
      {message && <div id="payment-message">{message}</div>}
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

渡されないパターンもあるってのを書いたらエラーは取れました。

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!stripe) {
      return;
    }

    //URLのクエリから値を取得する
    const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
      "payment_intent_client_secret"
    );

    // リダイレクト時にここに値が入る
    if (!clientSecret) {
      return;
    }

    stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret).then(({ paymentIntent }: PaymentIntentResult) => {
      switch (paymentIntent?.status) {
        case "succeeded":
          setMessage("Payment succeeded!");
          break;
        case "processing":
          setMessage("Your payment is processing.");
          break;
        case "requires_payment_method":
          setMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
          break;
        default:
          setMessage("Something went wrong.");
          break;
      }
    });
  }, [stripe]);
```

#### 参照

[Cannot invoke an object which is possibly ‘undefined’.](https://omkz.net/en-error-typescript-cannot-invoke/)